# str_replace adds 2x <br />

Tags: php, html, textarea

I have created a form that includes a  inorder to input the form to the DB I have added  n12br() like so...

```
$abme=nl2br($_POST['abme']);
```

(works fine!).

in order for the forum to reappear like when it was left i've added str_replace() like so...

```
<textarea value="" style="width:460px; height:150px" type="text" name="abme"><?php echo str_replace("<br />","\n","$abme"); ?></textarea>
```

however when executing the str_replace()function it in puts 2 "\n" for every 1 
 ....anyone know why or how to stop it?

Comment: What does the string `$abme` contain before the `str_replace()`? Please add this to your question.

Comment: @ithcy $abme= "about me" text the user has written when using the form previously.

Comment: Did you see this? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php#49516

Comment: @UKAWW please add the **actual value** of `$abme` before the `str_replace()` to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nl2br()` will not **replace** the newlines, but will **additionally** put in the `<br />`. So  you need to simply remove the `<br />`, not replace it with a newline: `str_replace('<br />','',"$abme");`

**Edit**

This is from a `php -a` session right now:

```
php > $string="abc\ndef";
php > echo $string;
abc
def
php > echo nl2br($string);
abc<br />
def
php >
```

Comment: I have no idea what the **Edit** section is about but first part solved the problem!!